# How to make a basic plot more beautiful using plot() function in R

Tags: r, plot

I am creating an R script to produce a chart consisting of multiple lines. I have produced a basic chart, and have managed to smooth each of the plotted lines. However, I want to beautify the chart by doing the following:

1. Currently, each line is plotted as a smoothed line. I want to plot the smoothed line using some other line type e.g. dash-dot, dash-dash-dot etc.
2. I want to add a legend to the chart, and display a line (same color as the line it represents in the main chart), in the legend.
3. Specify font size for the main chart title, x and y

Here is what I have so far:

```
dat  <- read.csv(filename, sep=',')

xvals <- dat$xvals
y1  <- dat$y1
y2  <- dat$y2
y3  <- dat$y3
y4  <- dat$y4
y5  <- dat$y5
y6  <- dat$y6

lo1 <- loess(y1~xvals)
lo2 <- loess(y2~xvals)
lo3 <- loess(y3~xvals)
lo4 <- loess(y4~xvals)
lo5 <- loess(y5~xvals)
lo6 <- loess(y6~xvals)

plot(xvals,y1, xlab='X label', ylab='Y label', type='n')
xl <- seq(min(xvals),max(xvals), (max(xvals) - min(xvals))/1000)
lines(xl, predict(lo1,xl), col='gray', lwd=1)
lines(xl, predict(lo2,xl), col='pink', lwd=1)
lines(xl, predict(lo3,xl), col='red', lwd=1)
lines(xl, predict(lo4,xl), col='cyan', lwd=1)
lines(xl, predict(lo5,xl), col='black', lwd=1)
lines(xl, predict(lo6,xl), col='green', lwd=1)

legend("topright", "(x,y)", pch=1, lty=c(1,1), # gives the legend appropriate symbols (lines)
       , lwd=c(1,1),col=c("blue","red"), inset = .02)
```

How do I modify the code above to implement the requirements 1 - 3 above?

As an aside, I am aware of ggplot. I think I'll stick with plot() - I find ggplot far too cryptic, puzzling and infuriating.

Comment: Fortunately, all three of your requirements are fairly basic functionality in R. Have you checked out Quick-R? There are some nice tutorials on [line graphs](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/line.html), [legends](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html), and [font sizes](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html). If you are still stuck, allow us to reproduce your data by using `dput(dat)` so that we can cut and paste it into our R sessions.

Comment: What nograpes said. You still have not responded to the request to post data for the question you asked earlier today.

Comment: @DWin: unfortunately, I am working on proprietary data. It requires too much effort to either obfuscate the data or create a reproducable example which encompasses the problem. I am using a different approach to solve the problem. If I manage to solve it, I will post the answer.

Comment: Please don't just erase all of the original material from your question and leave a note on why you erased it.

Comment: @Dason: I don't have enough points to remove it. I have voted for it to be closed. Given the rancour the question raised, I'm sure there are enough people on here who would like to see it closed.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: I agree with you, the docs are very difficult to understand. However, it makes it a lot more likely for people to answer your question if you have obviously Googled around a bit first. R has a pretty steep learning curve, and we're here to help, but it is frustrating for us when we see the same question 15 times. For the rest: try to show the newbies some [love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)

Comment: @nograpes: I accept I took the easy route. Its been a long day and I simply wanted to finish writing this script quickly and call it a night (its the wee hours of the morning here). Incidentally, the link you sent was very useful. I will use that to complete the script. Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli That's fine but I still don't agree with you erasing your original message.  That isn't helpful for anybody and the only reason I would downvote your question is because you erased the original content.

Comment: FYI With no answers, the OP could simply have deleted this question, I believe.

Comment: And that is still an option for him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I had started work on an answer already:

Make up some data:

```
dat <- data.frame(xvals=1:100,
                  y=matrix(rnorm(600),ncol=6))
```

Create formulae, apply `loess` and `predict`, collapse the results into a matrix:

```
formulae <- lapply(names(dat)[-1],
                   function(yvar) as.formula(paste(yvar,"xvals",sep="~")))
loessfits <- lapply(formulae,loess,data=dat)

xl <- with(dat,seq(min(xvals),max(xvals), length.out=1000))
pvals <- do.call(cbind,lapply(loessfits,predict,newdata=data.frame(xvals=xl)))
```

Set parameters (it's always worth going back and spending some more time reading `?par`):

```
## set box type (open), horizontal tick labels, axis label and title size
par(bty="l",las=1,cex.main=2,cex.lab=2)
```

Set up colo(u)rs and line types:

```
cvec <- c("gray","pink","red","cyan","black","green")
lvec <- 1:6
```

Create the plot:

```
matplot(xl,pvals,type="l",col=cvec,lty=lvec,
        xlab='X label', ylab='Y label')    
legend("topright", paste0("L",1:6), pch=1, lty=lvec,col=cvec, inset = .02)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll use the Quick R docs to set fontsize etc.

Comment: `formulae <- lapply(names(dat)[-1],
                   function(yvar) as.formula(paste(yvar,"xvals",sep="~")));
loessfits <- lapply(formulae,loess,data=dat)`  Pure genius!

Comment: I should have set the left margin a bit larger (e.g. `par(mar=c(5,5,2,2)+0.1)`

Comment: By the way, I *did* specify font size here (`cex.lab=2` ...)

Comment: @BenBolker: I was able to modify the script slightly and create a nice plot - thanks!. One thing though, I noticed from the plot that the smoothing/prediction I was using was giving misleading info in the chart - without going into too much detail, I want to revert to plotting just the raw data, without smoothing - how would I modify the code snippet you provided above to plot the raw data and not use any smoothing? (i.e. everything else remains the same otherwise)

Comment: just use `matplot(dat$xvals,dat[-1],...)`